# How to Hide A Grid/PopUP Using MVVM Pattern

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I am working On a App where a Grid/Popup Opens on a Listbox Tap , Grid Opens Successfully using IValueConverter but my problem is :

-> When I press back key on phone I hook up an RelayCommand on "Home_ViewModel.cs" , I was able to successfully called method but Grid Doesn't hide on BackKeyPress.

-> I called Base Class IsVisible property on BackKeyPress Command but didn't get to work correctly.

-> I don't know where I am working wrong either on OOPs concept or Binding Data on XAML. Kindly Look at My Code having Sky-Drive Link. Help Me In This !!!

Sky-Drive code link :

[Problematic Code Link](http://sdrv.ms/1a97b0a)

--> same qut. i Asked  [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5b6081dd-0d84-4823-b273-f6bfbe18b8ec/how-to-hide-a-gridpopup-using-mvvm-pattern?forum=wpdevelop) but didn't get any **response** .

Regards,

Pardeep

Comment: Hi Devs,

After 2-3 hours of Headache I got to know that My ViewModels are not Connect/Communicate with each other :

-> I would like to Connect/communicate Home_ViewModel.cs with AllPost_ViewModel.cs to hide My Grid Layout on BackKeyPress ("Grid" that opened on ListBox Tap) . 

-> As I am working with MVVM first time so I don't Know How to Use    GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger to connect my ViewModel. 

-> Help !!

Regards,

Pardeep

Answer (score 0):

Here are some samples: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945804/send-a-empty-message-or-notification-with-mvvm-toolkit-light), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628908/mvvm-light-pass-object-from-view-to-viewmodel).

In worth case, you can call from one VM to another via:

```
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<OtherVM>().Update();
```

A bit better way is

```
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<OtherVM>().MyCommand.Execute();
```

Use it only for fast testing, real project should work on Messages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Vitalii Vasylenko** I am disagree with your solution , so what I'd so far :

Register a Messenger on Allpost_ViewModel  constr. like :

```
public AllPost_ViewModel()
    {
        GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "String", executeThisFunction);
    }
```

and Pass a message from Home_ViewModel (on backkeypress) like :

```
public void ExecuteBackCommand(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.Visible)
        {                
            GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send<string>("Dummy text message", "String");
        }

    }
```

-> It successfully display a message via Message passing, But I didn't how to use this technique to accomplish my respective task.
 ->I just want to hide my popup on backkeypress.. Help !!
  -> updated link of my code is here : [Code Link](http://sdrv.ms/1ak0Q06)

Regards,
  Pardeep